# How can I auto deploy from a Git branch from VisualStudio.com to Azure?

Tags: git, azure, tfs, web-deployment

LS,

I am happily using the new VisualStudio.com service to host my repository. Now I want to deploy from that to Azure, which supports TFS and Git (not sure if it supports it together).

I'm assuming it is not possible right now, to do automatically from VS.com, because when I authorize my VS.com account, it tells me it can't find any projects.

Would love to hear more about the possibilities of doing this.

Comment: "*Lectori salutem*"? That has to be the most formal opening to any question I've read on the Internet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked it, and it is possible to deploy using VisualStudio.com and Git now.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time (early March 2013), visualstudio.com does not support automated git push to Windows Azure Web Sites.

When you check the "[Publishing a web site with Git](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/)" page, you see that (currently) deployment to Windows Azure Web Sites is supported for

- 'local files', a.k.a. 'git push azure master',
- CodePlex
- GitHub
- BitBucket

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. If you could add a reference to your claim, that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: You can't (as of today) continuously deploy from TFS+git to Azure.  What we've done is basically create a Bitbucket repo also, and use it solely for deployments.  TFS+git is our teams source control and work tracking system, but we also have a remote which points to bitbucket+git, which we push to as necessary.  Azure then hooks into the Bitbucket repo.

Answer (score 0):

you can always setup your repo on azure with your remote info. then manually call `git pull` from the cloud to get the newest commits.

(*not sure about this answer*)
if you can execute shell commands from visual studio you can add a hook to your git repo to ping a script on azure that will automatically do the pull. i use this methodology with github and php. nettuts+ has a great video explaining it http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh/

and here's some info on git hooks http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html

Comment: Could you explain how you would implement the first part of your answer on Azure? I don't see a way of doing that (other than using a VPS instance on Azure, which is exactly what I don't want).

Comment: do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: While you can provision OS images on Azure, that's not the way I'm using it. I'm merely deploying workers.